# Replace column with Summation value in R

Tags: r

Given a data frame in R

```
#   ID x1 x2 x3 x4
# 1  1  1  1  1  1
# 2  1  1  2  3  4
# 3  2  1  5  6  7
# 4  3  1  8  9  2
```

I want to replace the columns with their summation value

```
#   ID x1 x2 x3 x4
# 1  1  4 16 19 14
```

However, trying to set the sum directly replaces all the values with the sum:

```
for (nm in names(df)) {
  df[nm] = sum(df[nm])
}

#   ID x1 x2 x3 x4
# 1  1  4 16 19 14
# 1  2  4 16 19 14
# 1  3  4 16 19 14
# 1  4  4 16 19 14
```

Comment: `colSums`, but drop the "ID" column first, maybe?

Comment: Or, in the end just select the first record `df <- df[1, ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `ID` column is no longer needed. Then simply

```
colSums(df[, -1])
# x1 x2 x3 x4 
#  4 16 19 14
```